# Unable to segment handwritten characters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I am trying to extract handwritten numbers and alphabet from an image, for that i followed this stackoverflow link. It is working fine for most of the images where letter is written using marker but when i am using image where data is written using Pen it is failing miserably. Need some help to fix this.

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils import contours

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('xxx/pic_crop_7.png')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=350)
img=image.copy()

# Remove border
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
temp1 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)
temp3 = cv2.add(temp1, temp2)
result = cv2.add(temp3, image)

# Convert to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# thresh=cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations=1)

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[0]

MIN_AREA=45

digit_contours = []
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c)>MIN_AREA:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        digit_contours.append(c)
#         cv2.imwrite("C:/Samples/Dataset/ocr/segmented" + str(i) + ".png", image[y:y+h,x:x+w])


sorted_digit_contours = contours.sort_contours(digit_contours, method='left-to-right')[0]
contour_number = 0
for c in sorted_digit_contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('xxx/segment_{}.png'.format(contour_number), ROI)
    contour_number += 1
    
    
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

It is correctly able to extract the numbers when written using marker.

Below is an example:

**Original Image**

[image: Original Image]

**Correctly extracting charachters**

[image: Correctly extracting charachters]

Image where it fails to read.

**Original Image**

[image]

**Incorrectly Extracting**

[image]

Comment: Without exactly knowing what is happening in the code, it seems like the first step of your algorithm, is to  find rectangle contours, which is much easier than finding written numbers. After that step, within the rectangles it will try to figure out its content.

Comment: The image loses a lot of the content in the pre-processing part when you change to grayscale and blur it. I am not sure why you use gaussian blur on handwritten digits you want to recognize, you just make your job harder. Also the threshold operation with 0 as a threshold value is not likely to work. Check how your image looks like after the gaussian blur and after the threshold operation and you will see that most of the letters are already gone, and there lies the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you only need to adjust your parameter.
Because there is no vertical line in your handwritten characters' background, so I decided to delete them.

```
# Remove border
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)
result = cv2.add(temp2, image)
```

And it works.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked. I was wondering is there any way my single code can work for both if there is any vertical lines or not ?

Comment: In my method, first thing to do is detecting the image with your original code for every case. If the number of contour is under a specific number (ex: under 5 contour), the program will run again without vertical kernel, because that image might not have a vertical border.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that CodingPeter has given is perfectly fine, except that it may not be generic apropos the two test images you have posted. So, here's my take on it that might work on both of your test images, albeit with a little lesser accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 20)
plt.rcParams["image.cmap"] = 'gray'

img_rgb = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,1))
horiz = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
ctrs, _ = cv2.findContours(horiz,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for ctr in ctrs:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    if w < 20:
        cv2.drawContours(horiz, [ctr], 0, 0, cv2.FILLED)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,10))
vert = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
ctrs, _ = cv2.findContours(vert,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for ctr in ctrs:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    if h < 25:
        cv2.drawContours(vert, [ctr], 0, 0, cv2.FILLED)

th = th - (horiz | vert)
ctrs, _ = cv2.findContours(th,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
min_ctr_area = 400 # Min character bounding box area

for ctr in ctrs:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    # Filter contours based on size
    if w * h > min_ctr_area and \
    w < 100 and h < 100:
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
```

Of course some of the parameters here are hard-coded for filtering, which compare the contour height and width to ascertain whether it is a part of a line or maybe a character. With different images you may have to smartly change these values.

Comment: I tried your solution but yes the accuracy is not good. I am upvoting your solution because it works for both cases. Please upvote my question if you ind it usefull.